# PowerShell: How can I to force to get a result as an Array instead of Object

Tags: powershell

```
$result = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter
```

If I have 2 or more results, I get $x as array, but if I have only one result, a get $x as object. How to make it more correct, to always recieve array - empty, with one element or with some elements?

Comment: I'll drop the downvote this time, but you should search before asking. This is answered multiple times and is PowerShell basics = no research effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force Powershell to return an array when a call only returns one object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107428/how-can-i-force-powershell-to-return-an-array-when-a-call-only-returns-one-objec)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try `$x = @(get-aduser)`

The `@()` syntax forces the result to be an array

Comment: This won't result in an array containing an array if the result is an array? What if the function results `$null`? (PowerShell is so confusing because of all the magic they do sometimes.)

Comment: This is one of those annoying things about Powershell. With this solution you'll have an array with one element which is an array, so your Count property will be 1 even though the array inside could have many elements, which means you can't use it directly in a for loop.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner, in most cases you will not have array with single element.

Comment: Years later and I came across this problem again. This time a for loop was not entering because the array was turned into an object because it was one element. I had to check the Count property for null before entering the for loop.

Answer (score 19):

By the way, the other solutions in this question are not really the best way to do this, for the reasons stated in their comments.
A better way is simply to put a comma before the function, like

```
$result = ,(Get-ADUser -Filter $filter)
```

That will put an empty result into an empty array, a 1 element result into a 1 element array and a 2+ element result into an array of equal elements.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can use `$x=[array]get-aduser`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using an indexed value in a loop.  I fixed it by changing

```
$PatchGroupData.SCCM_Collection[$i]
```

to

```
@($PatchGroupData.SCCM_Collection)[$i]
```

Comment: This is effectively the same answer as the currently accepted one, but with less information.  Is there more you can add to your answer to flesh it out?

Comment: I will add comment. Some collections are internally `IEnumerable` type. IEnumerable does not have index (`[n]`) accessor, so they should be converted to array to have index. Theoretically, IEnumerable sequence CAN be infinite, so conversion to finite array not possible, but this is very rare case.