# Append an item to array not working?

Tags: powershell

The following code

```
$a = 1..5 | % {
    $l = $_, ($_+1), ($_+2)
    $r = $_ * 100
    $l, $r
    #$l.Add($r) # Error
}
$a | % { "[$_]" }
```

returns

```
[1 2 3]
[100]
[2 3 4]
[200]
[3 4 5]
[300]
[4 5 6]
[400]
[5 6 7]
[500]
```

However, I expected the following result?

```
[1 2 3 100]
[2 3 4 200]
[3 4 5 300]
[4 5 6 400]
[5 6 7 500]
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107428/how-can-i-force-powershell-to-return-an-array-when-a-call-only-returns-one-objec and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085077/powershell-how-can-i-to-force-to-get-a-result-as-an-array-instead-of-object?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,` does not append but creates a new array consisting of two items.

Use `+` to append an item, and then prefix it with `,` to escape flattening of the array by the pipeline:

```
$a = 1..5 | % {
    $l = $_, ($_+1), ($_+2)
    $r = $_ * 100
    ,($l + $r)
}
$a | % { "[$_]" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way but don't know why it works.

```
$a = 1..5 | % {
    $l = $_, ($_+1), ($_+2)
    $r = $_ * 100
    #$($l, $r)
    $l += $r
    ,@($l)
}
$a | % { "[$_]" }
```