# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd to DataTable rowcount is incorrect when its 1 record

Tags: sql-server, powershell

```
$sql=("select top 1 * FROM CollectionProfile")

$CollectionProfile = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$CollectionProfile = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $db -Query $sql -ErrorAction Stop  

$CollectionProfile.Rows.Count
```

RETURNS :0

But if I change the TOP count to 2 -

```
$sql=("select top 2 * FROM CollectionProfile")
```

RETURNS :2

Driving me crazy and yes, I could not find a single reference to this on the "innernets". I must be doing something wrong, but WHAT?

Answer (score 9):

When you use the query with TOP 1, Invoke-SqlCmd returns a DataRow.
When you use the query with TOP 2, Invoke-SqlCmd returns an Array of DataRows. Invoke-SqlCmd does not return a DataTable. You could change your code to force an array to be returned (see here: [force array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107428/how-can-i-force-powershell-to-return-an-array-when-a-call-only-returns-one-objec)), and then check the Count on it:

```
$sql = ("select top 1 * FROM CollectionProfile")

$CollectionProfile = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $db -Query $sql -ErrorAction Stop)

$CollectionProfile.Count #Returns 0 with Null, 1 with TOP 1, and 2 with TOP 2
```

Comment: Aha. I created a datatable and thought this was sufficient for it to behave as such. I am a newbie so I need to revisit on my own but thanks for clarifying this basic idea.

Comment: Thank you dugas. Very simple code change on my part but still need to get my head around the datatable that I was defining and what the difference is. A table is an array one could say. The whole invoke-sqlcmd command lends itself to being a table type within powershell - or at least thats how a dba might assume and go down the wrong path. I have a lot to learn .

Comment: @MBuchanan - you assigned a Datatable to the $CollectionProfile variable, but then you later assigned the return value from Invoke-Sqlcmd to the $CollectionProfile variable. Because of Dynamic Typing, the type of $CollectionProfile changed from a DataTable to whatever is returned from Invoke-Sqlcmd. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the column name from select statement in place of Rows, which will give correct result count.

Here in my example I gave name in place of rows which is my first column name in the select statement "Select top 1 * from Sysdatabases". This will give you correct result for top 1 or top 2 ..

```
 $sql=("select top 1 * FROM sysdatabases")
 $sysdatabases = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
 $sysdatabases = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Instance -Database $db -Query $sql -ErrorAction Stop  
 $sysdatabases.name.Count
```

Comment: I love this solution.  Very simple and works great.

Comment: doesn't work for TOP 1