# How can i always make a XML node an array even if only once occurance?

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

From my very limited Powershell knowledge, I seem to be getting arrays if the node repeats in a file but not if there is only one instance.  To solve the problem, I'm having to duplicate my code because `$ECN.PartRevisionData.PartRevision[$Index].ID` works for one XML file and `$ECN.PartRevisionData.PartRevision.ID` works for another one.  Is there a way to always have a node as an array even if there is only one entry in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force Powershell to return an array when a call only returns one object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107428/how-can-i-force-powershell-to-return-an-array-when-a-call-only-returns-one-objec)

Comment: Enclosing a variable in `@()` always converts it to an array. For example if `$a=1` then `@($a)` is an array with one item with value 1. Of coarse this pattern could be used to wrap more complicated expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to a foreach-object loop. This will treat no array as array[0] and normal arrays as arrays.

This will get you your desired effect. Every ID of a specific Part Revision

```
$ECN.PartRevisionData.PartRevision[$Index].ID | %{$_}
```

You can even do different scopes of information like this....It will get you every ID of every Part Revision

```
$ECN.PartRevisionData.PartRevision | %{$_.ID}
```

You could even go a step farther and do something like ...

```
$ECN.PartRevisionData.PartRevision | %{$_} | select id, name, location (whatever you want to bring back)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose the result in an new array:`@($ECN.PartRevisionData.PartRevision)`.
If the source isn't an array is will return an array, if the source is already an array, the same array will be returned. It will ***not*** create an embedded array which you might expect. This is standard PowerShell behavior:

```
PS C:\> $a = "a"
PS C:\> $b = @($a)
PS C:\> Write-Host $b ($b -is [array]) $b.count
a True 1
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $a = @("a", "b")
PS C:\> $b = @($a)
PS C:\> Write-Host $b ($b -is [array]) $b.count
a b True 2
```