# Force Powershell function to return Array

Tags: function, powershell, types, return

How can i force a Powershell function to return an Array?

This simple function for Example, if "C:\New folder" contains only 1 element, it will not return an Array.

```
function Get-AlwaysArray
{
    $returnArray = gci "C:\New folder"
    Write-Output $returnArray
}
(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()
```

There is already a Thread with a pretty good upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107428/how-can-i-force-powershell-to-return-an-array-when-a-call-only-returns-one-objec) But non of the answer works unfortunally.

Here is what i have tried:

```
function Get-AlwaysArray {
    [Array]$returnArray = gci "C:\New folder"
    Write-Output $returnArray   
}
(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()

function Get-AlwaysArray {
    $returnArray = @(gci "C:\New folder")
    Write-Output @($returnArray)   
}
(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()

function Get-AlwaysArray {
    $returnArray = @(gci "C:\New folder")
    Write-Output @($returnArray | Where-Object {$_})   
}
(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()

function Get-AlwaysArray {
    [Object[]]$returnArray = @(gci "C:\New folder")
    Write-Output @($returnArray | Where-Object {$_})   
}
(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()
```

The only way it would work is

```
function Get-AlwaysArray {
    $returnArray = gci "C:\New folder"
    Write-Output $returnArray 
}
@(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()
```

But i dont want to add this, everytime i call my function.

 What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should not try to encapsulate this. PowerShell's pipeline output is build around the premise you are trying to avoid. I would always surround with `@()` where I need to use the output and it is needed as an array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, use the array sub-expression operator @( ... ). This operator returns the result of one or more statements as an array. If there is only one item, the array has only one member.

```
$returnArray = @( Get-ChildItem "F:\PowerShell\A" )
```

Use **Write-Output** with the switch **-NoEnumerate** to prevent PowerShell from un-rolling the array.

```
Write-Output -NoEnumerate $returnArray
```

You can also effectively achieve the same result using **Write-Output** without using the **-NoEnumerate** by using the following syntax below.

```
Write-Output ,$returnArray
```

The comma in front of **$returnArray** effectively creates a new array with **$returnArray** as its only element. PowerShell then un-rolls this new single-element array, returning the original **$returnArray** intact to the caller.

Comment: Nice systematic overview, but note that you need parens in the last command: `Write-Output (,$returnArray)` or - better yet - omit the `Write-Output` and use just `, $returnArray`.

Answer (score -2):

try this one,

```
function Get-AlwaysArray
{

    $returnArray = Get-ChildItem "F:\PowerShell\A"
    Write-Output $()$returnArray
}

(Get-AlwaysArray).Gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                  
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: Bad idea, this will always add a`$Null` as the first item to your array.

Comment: Good point, @iRon. In addition to the unwanted `$null`, the approach is ineffective in Windows PowerShell. Only in PowerShell Core (v6+) do you get `$returnArray` as a _single_ output object (as the 2nd output object after the unwanted `$null`).

Comment: @trampCoder: To (indirectly) show that `$null` is being added, try `function foo() { Write-Output $() (1,2) }; foo | % { "[$_]" }` (inside an expandable string, `$null` expands to an empty string).