# PowerShell multidimensional Array issue

Tags: powershell

Im creating multidimensional array

```
cls
$b=[Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$a=4,5,6
[void]$b.Add($a)
$a1=7,8,9
[void]$b.Add($a1)

"Value is: "+$b[0][1]+" ."
"Size  is: "+$b.Count+" ."
""###
function arr(){
    $b=[Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    $a=4,5,6
    [void]$b.Add($a)
    $a1=7,8,9
    [void]$b.Add($a1)
    return $b
}
$c=arr
"Value is: "+$c[0][1]+" ."
"Size  is: "+$c.Count+" ."
```

Output:

```
Value is: 5 .
Size  is: 2 .

Value is: 5 .
Size  is: 2 .
```

Now all is correct. Function return the array in original state, without any deformations.
But I cant know beforehand array size, and when size of array is **1**, i get next problem:

```
cls
$b=[Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$a=4,5,6
[void]$b.Add($a)

"Value is: "+$b[0][1]+" ."
"Size  is: "+$b.Count+" ."
""###
function arr(){
    $b=[Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    $a=4,5,6
    [void]$b.Add($a)
    return $b
}
$c=arr
"Value is: "+$c[0][1]+" ."
"Size  is: "+$c.Count+" ."
```

Output:

```
Value is: 5 .
Size  is: 1 .

Value is:  .
Size  is: 3 .
```

When array moves out from function, he transforms from  multidimensional into the monodimensional, and there is no my value in output. How i can avoid this bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Powershell function to return Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341745/force-powershell-function-to-return-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return line in your code should look like that:

```
return (, $b)
```

This forces powershell to return your object at once. At default it returns each element separately.

Read more about it in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7
Search for Unary array expression