# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json unexpectedly produces a string instead of object array from single item array containing a string

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

File "array.json": ["bogus"]

```
PS C:\Users\Me> (Get-Content "array.json" | ConvertFrom-Json -NoEnumerate).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\Users\Me> (Get-Content "array.json" | ConvertFrom-Json).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

While probably useful sometimes, definitely not what I was unexpecting. Answer posted below to help others and avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell, single item arrays unroll when returned, see: [Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays).

[**Write-Output -NoEnumerate**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays#write-output--noenumerate)

> PowerShell likes to unwrap or enumerate arrays. This is a core aspect of the way PowerShell uses the pipeline but there are times that you don't want that to happen.

This is probably the biggest [pitfall/gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11107428/1701026) in PowerShell and not specific to the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlet, see e.g.: [How can I force Powershell to return an array when a call only returns one object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11107428/1701026).

The easiest (and most common) way to enforce an array is to use the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) (rather than the [Grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#grouping-operator--)):

```
@('["bogus"]' | ConvertFrom-Json).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

e.g.:

```
@('["bogus"]' | ConvertFrom-Json)[0]
bogus
```

See also questions along with: [unroll array single "Array subexpression operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+unroll+array+single+%22Array+subexpression+operator%22)

As **[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)** points out in this helpful [ConvertFrom-Json unpacks arrays with 1 item and behaves oddly with empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76996546/1701026) answer, you might also notice the difference in this behaviour with respect to versions prior to PowerShell 7+.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and additional info. I'll mark as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the question, the -NoEnumerate flag (strange name) is required to prevent a code disaster when you attempt to traverse the array...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.3